# Downloading the gzip file and Uncompressing to retrieve Content using IPHONE SDK on iphone and ipod touch devices

Tags: iphone, file, download, gzip, compression

I had the following questions related to downloading the file from the server.

a) Is it possible to download directly the GZIP (Compressed)file to the iphone device using IPHONE SDK.
b) If the compressed file can be downloaded , then how to uncompress it(using ZLIB or else...).

Answer (score 0):

Not at all sure about this, but if its http encoded with gzip, then that may well be auto-unzipped for you - as part of the http protocol - a guess and would need to be tested.  Also may not be appropriate for your situation.